# Closed-forms of infinite series with factorial in the denominator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, factorial, closed-form

How to evaluate the closed-forms of series

> \begin{equation}
> 1)\,\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n)!}\qquad\left|\qquad2)\,\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+1)!}\qquad\right|\qquad3)\,\, \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+2)!}\\
> \end{equation}

Of course Wolfram Alpha can give us the closed-forms
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n)!}&=\frac{e}{3}+\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{3\sqrt{e}}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+1)!}&=\frac{e}{3}+\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{3\sqrt{e}}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+2)!}&=\frac{e}{3}-\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}{3\sqrt{e}}
\end{align}
but how to get those closed-forms by hand? I can only notice that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3n+2)!}=e
\end{equation}
Could anyone here please help me? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**PS:** Please don't work backward.

Comment: I believe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610526) link might prove itself helpful.

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Lucian. BTW, where did you get those formulas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related techniques: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221519/identify-infinite-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-fracx4n4n). Here is an approach which enables you to tackle your problems. Let's consider the series

> $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}.  $$

Taking the Laplace transform gives

$$ F(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s^{3n+1}} = \frac{s^2}{s^3-1}. $$

To finish the problem you need to find the inverse Laplace of $F(s)$. One technique is partial fraction

$$ F(s) = \frac{1}{3(s-1)} + \frac{1}{3(s+1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)} + \frac{1}{3(s+1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)} .$$

**Notes:**

1) Laplace transform is defined as

> $$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-sx}dx. $$

2) Laplace transform of $x^m$ is

> $$ \frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{s^{m+1}} $$

3) Laplace transform of $e^{ax}$ is

> $$ \frac{1}{s-a}. $$

Or equivalently the inverse Laplace of $\frac{1}{s-a}$ is $e^{ax}$

$$  $$

Comment: It seems hard to me. I haven't learnt Laplace transform yet. +1 anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @V-Moy: It is not hard to learn. You are welcome.

Comment: @V-Moy: See what I added.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll learn it.

Comment: I think I understand the concept of Laplace transform. Let
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m!}
\end{equation}
where $m=an+b$. Multiplying both sides by $e^{-px}$, then integrating
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-px}\,dx&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty\frac{x^m}{m!}e^{-px}\,dx\\
F(p)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^{m+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^{an+b+1}}\\
&=\frac{p^{a-b-1}}{p^{a}-1}\\
\end{align}
then to get $f(x)$ we use the inverse of $F(p)$, right?

Comment: @V-Moy: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 7):

Another possible approach is to use the [discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). 
Let $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$. Then:
$$f(n)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}\right)=\mathbb{1}_{n\equiv 0\!\pmod{3}}(n),$$
hence:
$$\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(3n)!}}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n!}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\exp(1)+\exp(\omega)+\exp(\omega^2)\right)=\color{red}{\frac{e}{3}+\frac{2}{3\sqrt{e}}\cos\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.}$$
The other two series can be computed with the same technique, by noticing that:
$$f_1(n)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\omega^2\cdot\omega^n+\omega\cdot\omega^{2n}\right)=\mathbb{1}_{n\equiv 1\!\pmod{3}}(n),$$
$$f_2(n)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\omega\cdot\omega^n+\omega^2\cdot\omega^{2n}\right)=\mathbb{1}_{n\equiv 2\!\pmod{3}}(n).$$

Comment: Oh Lord, the previous answer is using Laplace transform and this one is using Fourier transform. Does 'transform' stand for transformation? If so, how many transformation are there in math? BTW, +1 Mr. D'Aurizio.

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved without advanced techniques. We have the Taylor series
$$
e^x = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$
As the questioner noted, plugging $x=1$ yields the equation $A+B+C=e$ connecting the three unknown sums. However, plugging in any cube root of unity also sheds light on the question because the numerators $x^n$ will repeat with period $3$. Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$; plugging $x = \omega$ yields $A + \omega B + \omega^2 C = e^{\omega}$, and plugging $x = \omega^2$ yields $A + \omega^2 B + \omega C = e^{\omega^2}$. We now have three equations that can be solved easily for the three unknowns $A$, $B$, and $C$. For instance, adding all three equations together yields
$$
3A = e + e^\omega + e^{\omega^2} = e + e^{-1/2}\left(\cos \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + i \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) + e^{-1/2}\left(\cos \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} + i \sin \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
$$ $$
= e + \frac{2}{\sqrt{e}} \cos \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
$$
in accordance with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Far superior to the accepted answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\ell = 0,1,2}$:

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I}_{\ell}&\equiv\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{3n + \ell}!}=
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\delta_{k,3n + \ell} \over k!}
> =\sum_{n,k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over k!}
> \oint_{\atop{\atop\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}}{1 \over z^{3n + \ell - k + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\atop{\atop\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}}{1 \over z^{\ell + 1}}
> \bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{1 \over z^{3}}^{n}}
> \bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{z^{k} \over k!}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\atop{\atop\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}}{1 \over z^{\ell + 1}}
> \,{1 \over 1 - 1/z^{3}}\,\expo{z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\atop{\atop\verts{z}\ =\ a\ >\ 1}}
> {z^{2 - \ell} \over z^{3} - 1}\,\expo{z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{m = -1}^{1}{z_{m}^{2 - \ell}\expo{z_{m}} \over 3z_{m}^{2}}\qquad
> \mbox{where}\qquad z_{m} \equiv \exp\pars{2m\pi\ic \over 3}\,,\quad m = -1,0,1
> \end{align}

Then,
\begin{align}
{\cal I}_{\ell} &= {1 \over 3}
\sum_{m = -1}^{1}z_{m}^{-\ell}\expo{z_{m}}
={1 \over 3}\,\expo{} + {2 \over 3}\,\Re\pars{z_{1}^{-\ell}\expo{z_{1}}}
={1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
+{2 \over 3}\,\Re\pars{\expo{-2\ell\pi\ic/3}\exp\pars{\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
+{2 \over 3}\,
\Re\pars{\expo{-2\ell\pi\ic/3}\exp\pars{-\,\half + {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
+{2 \over 3\root{\expo{}}}\,
\Re\exp\pars{\bracks{{\root{3} \over 2} - {2\pi \over 3}\,\ell}\ic}
\end{align}

> $$
> {\cal I}_{\ell}\equiv\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{3n + \ell}!}
> ={1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
> +{2 \over 3\root{\expo{}}}\,\cos\pars{{\root{3} \over 2} - {2\pi \over 3}\,\ell}
> \,,\qquad\ell = 0,1,2
> $$

$$\begin{array}{rclcl}
{\cal I}_{0}&=&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{3n}!}}
&=&{1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
+{2 \over 3\root{\expo{}}}\,\cos\pars{{\root{3} \over 2}}
\\[5mm]
{\cal I}_{1}&=&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{3n + 1}!}}
&=&{1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
+{2 \over 3\root{\expo{}}}\
\overbrace{\cos\pars{{\root{3} \over 2} - {2\pi \over 3}}}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\sin\pars{{\root{3} \over 2} - {\pi \over 6}}}}}
\\[5mm]
{\cal I}_{2}&=&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{3n + 2}!}}
&=&{1 \over 3}\,\expo{}
+{2 \over 3\root{\expo{}}}\
\underbrace{\cos\pars{{\root{3} \over 2} - {4\pi \over 3}}}
_{\ds{\color{#c00000}{-\sin\pars{{\root{3} \over 2} + {\pi \over 6}}}}}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Although I don't understand your approach but +1 Mr. Marin. Thanks for providing me the general formula for my OP. ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Answer (score 1):

Let: $f(0)=1, f'(0)=0, f''(0)=0,f'''(x)=f(x)$

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{e^x + e^{ux} + e^{vx}} {3} $$ $$u = -1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2; v= u^2 = -1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2$$

$$ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{3}+\frac{e^{-x/2}}{3}\cdot (e^{i\sqrt{3}/2}+e^{-i\sqrt{3}/2})$$
$$ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{3}+\frac{e^{-x/2}}{3}\cdot 2cos((\sqrt{3}/2) x)$$

$$ f(1) = \frac{e}{3}+\frac{2 cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}{3 \sqrt{e}}$$