# Sum of $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(kn)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, closed-form

Does a closed form exist for

> $$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(kn)!}$$

in terms of $k$ and other functions? The best that I have been able to do is solve the case where $k=1$, since the sum is just the infinite series for $e$. I would guess that any closed form must involve the exponential function, but am at a loss to prove it.

Comment: For small $k$ there are fairly easy to find closed forms involving functions like cos, cosh. In the general case the closed form is a messy expression involving the generalised hypergeometric function.

Comment: sum diverges at $k=0$ and conveges to $\cos (ix)$ for $k=2$

Comment: @gt6989b you could also write $\cosh(1)$ for $k=2$

Comment: If you could find a general function that has the property $f(x)=f^{(k)}(x)$, and $f^{(k)}(a)=1$ for all $k$ and fixed $a$, then you could make this the Taylor series of that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closed-forms of infinite series with factorial in the denominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914176/closed-forms-of-infinite-series-with-factorial-in-the-denominator)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $(c_n)$ is any sequence with period $k$ (that is, $c_{n+k}=c_n$) then it's possible to evaluate $\sum c_n/n!$ using tricks involving $k$-th roots of unity.

Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/k}$. Consider the $k$ sequences

$s_0:1,1,1\dots$

$s_1: 1, \omega,\omega^2,\omega^3,\dots$

$s_2: 1, \omega^2,\omega^4,\omega^6,\dots$

$s_3: 1, \omega^3,\omega^6,\omega^9,\dots$

...

$s_{k-1}: 1, \omega^{k-1},\omega^{2(k-1)},\dots$.

Using tricks analogous to finding Fourier coefficients you can find $a_0,\dots a_{k-1}$ so that $$(c_n)=a_0(s_0)+\dots+a_k(s_{k-1}).$$

Hence $$\sum\frac{c_n}{n!}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_j\sum_n\frac{\omega^{jn}}{n!}
=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_je^{\omega^j}.$$

If you do that for your sequence you get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(kn)!}=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\omega^j}.$$

**Edit:** Thomas Andrews makes a comment that I should have included: Since the original sum is real, it follows that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(kn)!}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\cos 2\pi j/k}\cos(\sin2\pi j/k).$$

**Edit:** If one is familiar with "abstract harmonic analysis", here just harmonic analysis on compact abelian groups, one sees that those "tricks analogous to finding Fourier coefficients" are in fact finding Fourier coefficients for a certain function on the group $\Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$.

Comment: And, since the imaginary part is necessarily zero, this also gives the formula:$$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\cos 2\pi j/k}\cos(\sin2\pi j/k)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, I shoulda said that, thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, this is a Riemann sum for $\int_{0}^{1} e^{\cos 2\pi x}\cos(\sin 2\pi x)\,dx$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that's interesting. As is the fact that it follows that that integral equals $1$.

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying to see if I could prove that directly.

Comment: It's not hard to show with complex analysis, since it can be seen as the real part of $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z}\,dz$. But I'm not seeing a way to do it with first-year-calculus logic.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know whether it's "direct": Go back to the complex version: $\int_0^1e^{e^{2\pi it}}\,dt$. Expand the exponential... close to going in circles here..

Answer (score 10):

This is a different approach to the idea in David Ullrich's answer.

---

As long as $\frac nk\not\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{2\pi ij\frac nk}
&=\frac{e^{2\pi in}-1}{e^{2\pi i\frac nk}-1}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
if $\frac nk\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{2\pi ij\frac nk}
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}1\\
&=k
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(kn)!}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\overbrace{\left(\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{2\pi ij\frac nk}\right)}^{1\iff\frac nk\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n!}\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(e^{2\pi ij/k}\right)^n}{n!}\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\large e^{2\pi ij/k}}\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\cos(2\pi j/k)+i\sin(2\pi j/k)}\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\cos(2\pi j/k)}\left(\cos(\sin(2\pi j/k))+i\sin(\sin(2\pi j/k))\right)\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{\cos(2\pi j/k)}\cos(\sin(2\pi j/k))
\end{align}
$$
The last step follows since the imaginary parts of the $j$ and $k-j$ terms cancel.

Comment: Well, they cancel because the value is obviously real :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: indeed, but since we have introduced complex numbers, we should show that the *computed* answer is actually real.

Comment: I can't understand how did you write the first equality after "Thus,". Could you explain this a bit for me, please?

Comment: @user486600: for a proof that the quantity in parentheses is $[\,k\mid n\,]$ see the Preliminaries of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2638202).

Answer (score 0):

Sum expressed by a special function:

$$\color{red}{\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(k n)!}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\Gamma (k
   n+1)}=\color{red}{E_{k,1}(1)}$$

where: $\color{red}{E_{k,1}(1)}$ is generalized [Mittag-Lefflere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html) function.