# Calculate sum of infinite series by solving a differential equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, factorial

Calculate the sum of the infinite series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n)!}$$ by solving an aptly chosen differential equation.

I know that one can solve a differential equation by assuming that we can write the solution as a power series in the form
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n$$ and then find all the different values for $a_n$'s. I'm trying to figure out how to to it the other way around? How am I supposed to find the differential equation when I have the infinite sum already?

**Update**
I've started off supposing there exists some solution, to the differential equation of the form
$$p(x)y''(x)+q(x)y'(x)+r(x)y(x)=0,$$ that can be written as 
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-x_0)^n. $$
Since I already know this solution should be of the form $$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n)!}$$ I know that $a_n=\frac{1}{(3n)!}, x=1, x_0=0$. Furthermore, writing $$y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\ a_n(x-x_0)^{n-1} \ \ and \ \ y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)\ a_n(x-x_0)^{n-2}. $$ and filling this in the differential equation I finally end up with the equation
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(p(x)\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{(3(n+2))!} + q(x)\frac{(n+1)}{(3(n+1))!}+r(x)\frac{1}{(3n)!} \right)=0$$
I think that all the functions $p(x), q(x) \ $and $ r(x)$ should be evaluated at $x=1$. However, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I hate questions where you have to use a particular method when the solution is obvious by a different method!

Comment: I guess the idea is to consider the differential equation $$y^{(3)}=y.$$ Can you proceed from there?

Comment: OP: Since you accepted instantaneously an answer, surely you realize that this answer is taking things backwards, first producing the solution (with no explanation), then showing (or saying that one can show) that this solution solves a differential equation, instead of the other way around, as you asked?

Comment: Related : [Sum of $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(kn)!}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708900)

Comment: @Did You're right. It isn't a complete answer and I shouldn't accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to sum a series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ of constant terms it often helps to consider the function $y(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$. In the case at hand we have
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^{3n}\over (3n)!}=1+{x^3\over 3!}+{x^6\over 6!}+{x^9\over 9!}+\ldots\ .\tag{1}$$
Then
$$y'(x)={3x^2\over3!}+{6x^5\over 6!}+{9x^8\over 9!}\ldots={x^2\over2!}+{x^5\over5!}+{x^8\over8!}+\ldots,\qquad y''(x)={x\over1!}+{x^4\over 4!}+{x^7\over 7!}+\ldots$$
and therefore 
$$y'''(x)=1+{x^3\over 3!}+{x^6\over 6!}+\ldots=y(x)\ .$$
It follows that this function satisfies the differential equation
$$y'''-y=0\ .$$
Now find the general solution of this ODE. Among the $\infty^3$ solutions there is exactly one that also satisfies the initial conditions $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$, $y''(0)=0$, as does the $y(x)$ in $(1)$. If $y_*(\cdot)$ is this solution then $y_*(1)$ is the sum of your series.

Comment: Sorry for the late question, but why is $y'''-y=0$?  I've been trying to calculate it, but I get $y'''= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+6)!}x^{3n+6}$. But  $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+6)!}x^{3n+6}-   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n)!}x^{3n}$ is not equal to $0$

Comment: @Noah_K: Your $y'''$ is wrong.

Comment: Why do you write $3n$ as exponent for $x$?

Comment: And how do you get $y(0)=1$? Do you assume that $0^0=1$?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat If you write out the derivatives you'll see why he uses $3n$ as the exponent

Comment: @Noah_K I found $y'''(x)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3(n-1)}}{(3(n-1))!}$. But this means the first term of the third derivative has a negative factorial in it. There does not seem to be consensus on how to deal with that. If a negative factorial is infinity, then indeed $y''' - y = 0$. But did the answerer choose the $3n$ exponent because that choice makes $y'''-y=0$ work; or did the $3n$ follow logically from the summation $\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{k}x^{k}$? If he chose it to make the DE work, how to find this without knowing it in advance?

Comment: The series will start at $n=1$ so you wont be dealing with a negative factorial.

Answer (score 2):

From a polynomial or power series $f(x)$ you can "punch out" the odd degree terms by taking the even part $\frac12(f(x)+f(-x))$. In a similar fashion you can produce "holes" with period $3$ in the coefficient sequence by combining $f(e^{ik\frac{2\pi}3}x)$, $k=-1,0,1$.

As the remaining coefficients in the given series can be interpreted to be every third coefficient of the exponential series,
it can be written the evaluation at $x=1$ of $$
\frac13(e^x+e^{wx}+e^{\bar wx})
$$
with $w^3=1$, i.e., $w=e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}=\frac12(-1+i\sqrt3)$.

This can now easily be transformed into a linear ODE of order 3. (Which, arguably, is backwards from what is intended for the task. So you got to find an argument directly starting from the periodicity of $n!a_n$.)