# How to find $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(kn)!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> I want to calculate $$S_k = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{(kn)!}$$ when $k\in\Bbb N ^*$.

I tried to find a recurrence equation for $k$, but I found nothing really interesting.

I already know that for $k=1, S_1 = e$ and $S_2 = ch(1)$, but I don't know what to do for $k\geq 3$.

Comment: It may be easier to compute the function $\sum x^{kn}/(kn)!$, and when you are done plug in $x=1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm sorry, I didn't find it when I searched. What should I do? Delete it? (The first question of this type is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708900/sum-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac1kn )

Comment: It only should be marked as "duplicate", that's all. But it's not so important. Some user can vote for close (reason: duplicate), there is nothing to do for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done via *series multisection*. If one has a power series
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$ then
one can pick out the terms with $k\mid n$ as follows.
Let $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/k)$ and consider
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}f(\zeta^j x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\zeta^{jn}x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\zeta^{jn}.$$
The inner sum is a GP and is zero, unless $k\mid n$, in which case
it equals $k$. Therefore
$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}f(\zeta^j x)
=k\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{km}x^{km}.$$
Taking $x=1$,
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{km}=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}f(\zeta^j).$$

So,
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac1{(km)!}=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\exp(\zeta^j)
=\frac1k\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\exp(\cos(2\pi j/k))\cos(\sin(2\pi j/k))$$
on taking real parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted it because you proved the formula.

Answer (score 6):

This is closely related to series multisection.

Let $$f(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac1{n!}z^n=e^z$$

Let $a_n=\frac1{n!}$.

Then, $$S_k=\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_{km}z^{km}$$ where $z=1$.

By the multisection formula, we immediately obtain
$$S_k=\frac1k\sum^{k-1}_{p=0}\text{exp}\left(e^{\frac{2\pi ip}{k}}\right)$$

**THOUGHTS:**

How to evaluate $S_\infty$ from the formula for $S_k$ I derived above?

**Follow-up:**

$S_\infty$ is a Riemann sum!
$$S_\infty=\int_0^\infty e^{e^{2\pi ix}}dx$$

**RESPONSE TO COMMENT:**

For reference: [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you tell me more about this formula? I cannot find any reference in my language (French). Is there another name for it?

Comment: @MiKiDe Please see my edited answer.